# Probability of X winning N number of games

Tags: probability, probability-theory, permutations, combinations

Say there is a player X. 
X has to choose and play one of the 4 games - Game A, Game B, Game C, Game D

```
Probability of choosing Game A = pA
Probability of choosing Game B = pB
Probability of choosing Game C = pC
Probability of choosing Game D = pD
```

pA != pB != pC != pD

X has to win the game.

```
Probability of X winning Game A = pWA
Probability of X winning Game B = pWB
Probability of X winning Game C = pWC
Probability of X winning Game D = pWD
```

pWA != pWB != pWC != pWD

So the probability that X will choose and win Game A is pA*pWA.. and similarly for B,C and D.

```
P(A) = pA*pWA
P(B) = pB*pWB
P(C) = pC*pWC
P(D) = pD*pWD
P(N) = pA*(1-pWA) + pB*(1-pWB) + pC*(1-pWC) + pD*(1-pWD)
```

where P(N) is probability of not winning the game

Now, X plays 3 games continuously.
So the probability that X will win 3 games of Game A is : P(A) * P(A) + P(A)
Similarly for other possibilities,

```
P(AAA) = P(A) * P(A) * P(A)
P(BDA) = P(B) * P(D) * P(A)
P(ACN) = P(A) * P(C) * P(N)
.
.
.
P(NNN) = P(N) * P(N) * P(N)
```

***NOW, how do I find the probability of X winning n number of games?*** 
i.e

```
P(X winning 0 games)
P(X winning 1 game)
P(X winning 2 games)
P(X winning 3 games)
```

I am assuming it will be something like this..

```
P(0) = P(NNN)
P(1) = P(ANN) + P(NAN) + P(NNA) + .....
P(2) = P(AAN) + P(ANA) + P(ABN) + .....
P(3) = P(AAA) + P(BBB) + P(CCC) + P(DDD)
```

P(0) and P(3) are done.
P(1) and P(2) will involve all permutations, so how do I generalize the formula for them?

And If there is anything wrong in how I proceeded, please point it out. 
Thanks.

Comment: If $3$ games are played you must not add up the chances, as you do. He plays and wins $A$ first time *and* plays and wins $A$ the second time *and* plays and wins $A$ the third time. Not *or*. You must apply multiplication here.

Comment: @drhab  Eep.. yes. modified the question now.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernouilli_trials

Comment: @SurajM.S  Bernaulli's trials involve `Independent repeated trials of an experiment`.. This applies to trials of the same experiment right, where probabilities of success is the same for each trial. 
In this case, each trial may be of different experiments, and their probabilities may vary.

Answer (score 0):

$n$ independent experiments take place. The experiment 'succeeds' if the game is won. For every experiment you have the same probability of succes: $p:=1-P(N)$. The number of successes  is then [binomially distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $n$ and $p$.

Comment: But the probability of success is not the same for each experiment.

Comment: The probability that the first game is won is $1-P(N)$, do you agree? Then comes the second game. What has changed then?...I do not see a difference with the first game. The scenarion is completely the same. Again there is a probability of $1-P(N)$ that this game is won.